# CA is repeated in IIS https response, what is the configuration section to be checked?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

This is about the https of the payment service provider we're using. We've notified them about the problem which causes some android devices to show SSL error message when the browser is redirected to the https address. But they haven't found the solution and so I'm trying to find a hint for them.

In the output of `openssl s_client -connect pep.shaparak.ir:443`, you can see that item 1 and item 2 are the same. If the server was apache, I guess that was because of mistake in content of the file referenced in `SSLCertificateChainFile`. But I don't know the equivalent in `IIS`.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 CN = T\C3\9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sunucu Sertifikas\C4\B1 Hizmetleri, C = TR, O = T\C3\9CRKTRUST Bilgi \C4\B0leti\C5\9Fim ve Bili\C5\9Fim G\C3\BCvenli\C4\9Fi Hizmetleri A.\C5\9E. (c) Kas\C4\B1m  2005
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=IR/ST=TEHRAN/L=TEHRAN/OU=IT DEPARTMENT/O=SHAPARAK ELECTRONIC CARD PAYMENT NETWORK CO. (PJS)/CN=pep.shaparak.ir
   i:/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sunucu Sertifikas\xC4\xB1 Hizmetleri/C=TR/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m  2005
 1 s:/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sunucu Sertifikas\xC4\xB1 Hizmetleri/C=TR/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m  2005
   i:/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1/C=TR/L=Ankara/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m 2005
 2 s:/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sunucu Sertifikas\xC4\xB1 Hizmetleri/C=TR/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m  2005
   i:/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1/C=TR/L=Ankara/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m 2005
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
((blah blah))
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=IR/ST=TEHRAN/L=TEHRAN/OU=IT DEPARTMENT/O=SHAPARAK ELECTRONIC CARD PAYMENT NETWORK CO. (PJS)/CN=pep.shaparak.ir
issuer=/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sunucu Sertifikas\xC4\xB1 Hizmetleri/C=TR/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m  2005
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4518 bytes and written 634 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: FE169BDE3DEFEC4C332981D093AC4A1BAC2A2D0F88C99A7D60428073A6154554
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 7997043C235AC35382526AC89469E8896D0BCB61289A324520665B9B251462E560C26CC9A1372D887D5F9A1F20844F84
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    ((blah blah))

    Start Time: 1404818844
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
DONE
```

Thanks!